# Undefined Reference Error when converting PHP variable to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps

For an internet programming assignment we need to parse data from .json files using PHP.

Here is the php code where I get the text from the files:

```
$pointsA = json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents("pointsA.json")), true);
$pointsB = json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents("pointsB.json")), true);
$mapCenter = utf8_encode(file_get_contents("center.json"));
```

And here is the code where I attempt to pass it to javascript.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mapCenter, aMatches, bMatches;
        mapCenter = <?php echo $mapCenter;?>;
        aMatches = <?php echo json_encode($aMatches);?>;
        bMatches = <?php echo json_encode($bMatches);?>;
    </script>
```

This last block is located in the  of the html code, and it is located before any of the other code used. SPecifically, the head looks like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Route Plotting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mapCenter, aMatches, bMatches;
        mapCenter = <?php echo $mapCenter;?>;
        aMatches = <?php echo json_encode($aMatches);?>;
        bMatches = <?php echo json_encode($bMatches);?>;
    </script>
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAdt2pyYUsR8xq7n_0InalSC7mahTk6Hcg&amp;libraries=places">
    </script>
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="googleMapsCalendar.js">
    </script>
</head>
```

When I render the webpage in Google Chrome I get the following console error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var index.php:12
Uncaught ReferenceError: mapCenter is not defined
```

The line number for the first error message is not correct, as it leads to a comment. I believe it is talking about first line in the first  tag that i posted.

The second error message points to this piece of code:

```
var mapCenterLoaction = new google.maps.LatLng(mapCenter['center']['lat'], mapCenter['center']['lat']);
```

Which is the fist place I attempt to use 'mapCenter' variable in an external javascript file.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

here is the generated code from inspecting the first  element in the head:

```
        var mapCenter, aMatches, bMatches;
        mapCenter = var center=
{
    "center": { "lat" : "44.974", "long" : "-93.234" },
    "zoom": "15"
};
        aMatches = [0];
        bMatches = [0];
```

Does that mean that I don't need the 'var' keyword when defining these, but only to echo them in?

If that's the case, how do I refer to these variables in an external javascript file?

SECOND EDIT:

The issue was that the file that I was parsing which I thought was json was actually javascript. Thank you to all who contributed to solving my problem!

Comment: look at the generated source code, e.g. load your page, do a "view source". that'll show you what PHP spit out, and paste a copy here.

Comment: It would seem that `center.json` does not contain json but javascript code: A variable declaration without the trailing `;`. You should make sure it is either valid json or valid javascript and include it accordingly.

Comment: This is what is in `center.json` : `var center=
{
    "center": { "lat" : "44.974", "long" : "-93.234" },
    "zoom": "15"
}`

Comment: You are definitely right, that was the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
mapCenter = '<?php echo $mapCenter;?>';
```

I think you get this error because $mapCenter is empty.

Comment: Wouldn't it have the value assigned to it from this line of PHP:      $mapCenter = utf8_encode(file_get_contents("center.json"));

Comment: This produced the following output: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`